# How to filter a view's attachment by clicking the links on the main view and using AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I have a view listing node titles of a content type, using Views Accordion to group them by categories. And an attachment display attached to it which shows an individual node filtered by node id (exposed filter or contextual, I can use any of them).

What I want to achieve is, if I click on a title on the main view, the attachment should be updated via AJAX to show that node.

[image: Sketch]

Comment: This could be achieved easily with writing some custom jQuery. If you want i will put an answer here with how to do it

Comment: Thanks, @doron. I'd be happy to see your solution. I was able to solve that, about half an hour ago, following the instructions on this post: http://mrkadin.com/blog/node/70 I wanted to post the solution in the course of the day.

Comment: Your link is exactly what i was gonna write you. You saved me some typing :)

Comment: The link is dead, you can find it here https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20151220165952/http://mrkadin.com:80/blog/node/70